# How do i implement a generic class that calls a static method of specified interface in java

Tags: java, generics, interface, static-methods

I have the following code, which does not work as intended.
When I call the Chumbles constructor with Grumbo as type it calls every time the static method of the Schlami interface instead of the method of Grumbo.
What am I missing here? and what workaround, and I am pretty sure I need one, should I implement?

Thanks in advance!

p.s.: I feel already sorry for my naming convention

EDIT: my intention:
I have several classes that all need to be converted to JSON and from JSON back into a class.
additional to that I have a wrapper class for each of them that holds an array list of the classtype and can convert that list back and forth to JSON.

so I tried to build an generic class that I can reuse to minify code. my attempt was to implement an interface that guarantees the existence of both methods and to call them in that generic class. but this seems not to work.

in know that the object cast doesn't work. that function should never be called anyway

```java
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Chumbles<Grumbo> schleem = new Chumbles<>("test");

        System.out.println("pause");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Chumbles<T extends Schlami> {

    public Chumbles(String s){

        T fleeb = T.fromJSON(s);
        System.out.println(fleeb.toJSON());
    }
}
```

```java
public class Grumbo implements Schlami {

    String s;

    public Grumbo(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toJSON() {
        return "GrumboJSON";
    }

    public static Grumbo fromJSON(String s) {
        return new Grumbo("Grumbo Success ");
    }
}
```

```java
public interface Schlami {

    String toJSON();

    static <T> T fromJSON(String json){

        return (T) new Object();
    }
}
```

EDIT2: so I use now a combination of generic factoryclasses and non static call of fromJSON. it feels gross to use new Grumbo().fromJSON(json) but I'll use it till I find a better workaround. thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: `Chumbles<T extends Schlami>`? This doesn't make sense

Comment: And why would anything need to implement or extend Schlami if the interface has no instance methods?

Comment: Could your question in fact be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in disguise? You may want to tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: `(T) new Object()`: Guaranteed to crash. Static interface methods aren't supposed to be used like this.

Comment: Short answer to your question: Java doesn't have a way to do this; make explicit factory classes instead.

Comment: i have several classes that all need to be converted to JSON and from JSON back into a class. 
additional to that i have a wrapper class for each of them that holds an array list of the classtype and can convert that list back and forth to JSON.

so i tried to build an generic class that i can reuse to minify code. 
my attempt was to implement an interface that guarantees the existence of both methods and to call them in that generic class. but this seems not to work. 

in know that the object cast doesnt work. that function should never be called anyways

Comment: Why not use an existing JSON parser like Gson or Jackson? Otherwise, I'd recommend following suit by taking advantage of class literals. If you don't want to use reflection to map properties, which literals would require, you could always use the nullary approach where you instantiate a nullary object (using default/nullary constructor) and call `fromJson(String)` on it, which populates the properties.

Answer (score -1):

So, your question is why at "T.fromJSON(s);" the method from Schlami instead of the method from Grumbo is called?
Since T extends Schlami, Schlami is always the class referenced when calling static methods.
**Please note, that you cannot override static methods!**

I would suggest just calling the method by "Grumbo.fromJSON();". If you need to override the method, you could turn Schlami in an abstract class, override the method in Grumbo and call it from object-context.

Comment: but T needs to be extended by Schlami. otherwise i cant call the schlami methods. 
an abstract class could be the solution but i would rather try an other workaround. 

just using Grumbo doesnt solve anything because another Schlami-class cant work with that.

Comment: What you could do, if you want to stick to static methods, is to add ab argument to your Chumbles constructor to have the class of T present and then call method by class.getMethod():
public Chumbles(String s, Class<T> clazz) {
T fleeb = clazz.getMethod("fromJSON", String.class).invoke(null, s) ;
}